# Why when applying symmetries do you read from right to left?

Tags: group-theory

I am new to group theory, and I was just curious why the convention for applying symmetries was to read from right to left? Most mathematical operations I am aware of are read from left to right.

Comment: Function composition is always from right to left: when I write $f(g(h(x)))$ I mean apply $h$ first, then $g$, then $f$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "Always" is a bit strong.  In analysis, I can't recall ever seeing functions composed left-to-right, but I often have in algebra.  In Herstein's "Topics in Algebra" it's done that way.

Comment: But some authors like Herstein compose functions from left to right. Think of writing eff of ex as $(x)f$.

Comment: Sure, I guess I should have said "usually," that was a little sloppy. I myself have written a few blog posts where composition is in "diagrammatic order." I had in mind the function compositions the OP was likely to have seen.

Comment: You can do linear transformations as $Ax$ or as $x^TA^T$.

Comment: When you compose transformations of the type $T_a:x \to a^{-1}xa$, you use (in a certain way) the two types...

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetries"?

Comment: Since this post has the Group Theory tag, I can point out that the proportion of group theorists who compose from left to right is probably close to a half. Also the software packages GAP and Magma both compose from left to right (which admittedly causes confusion among some new users).

Comment: It really depends on whether you use prefix or suffix notation for functions. Many people use suffix, and then symmetries/permutations/etc are composed left-to-right. As Derek Holt says, many group theorists use left-to-right composition, and even write morphisms on the right (suffix notation); e.g., Hanna Neumann’s book, _Varieties of Groups_, uses suffix notation throughout.

Comment: Permutations present a particular annoyance, because when they are written in disjoint cycle notation, *each cycle* is interpreted left-to-right; so if you are composing right-to-left, you are doing weird jumps where you scan something left-to-right, then you jump right, then you go left-to-right again, then you jump right, etc. This is why some authors (like Herstein) treat permutations with a “left-to-right throughout” rule; others don’t. Ring theorists like morphisms on the left because it makes every module into a bimodule, and the scalar identity looks like associativity: $(ra)f = r(af)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rough convention in mathematics (and there will be lots of exceptions to this!) about when we think of applying group elements left to right and when right to left. Two really important examples of groups that you might have met are matrix groups (ie groups where each group element is a matrix), and permutation groups (groups where you think of each element as a permutation, or shuffling around elements).

An $n\times n$ matrix is a function from $R^n\rightarrow R^n$. Now we typically apply functions from right to left: ie $f\circ g \circ h (x) = f(g(h(x))))$, ie we apply $h$ first, then $g$ then $h$. So if I was looking at a matrix group and I saw $fgh$, I would typically expect to apply $h$ first.

The other way of thinking of groups is as permutations, and these are typically written left to right instead. We sometimes use greek letters for permutations. Let $\pi$ be swap the 1st and 2nd item, and let $\rho$ be swap 2nd and 3rd. Then if I write $\pi\rho$, I'd typically expect this to mean swap 1st and 2nd, and then swap 2nd and 3rd, ie apply $\pi$ first. Eg

ABC <-- start with this

BAC <-- apply $\pi$

BCA <-- apply $\rho$

Which way is more right? Well it depends how we are thinking of a group. And confusingly (or perhaps interestingly), every finite group can be thought of as a matrix group, or as a permutation group, so there is always a way of thinking of it as one way or the other! A tad confusing, but it's nice to have options!